# clear piped output without interrupting program?

Tags: bash, pipe

I am running a program (pianobar) piped to a text file, that outputs every second.  The resulting file ("pianobarout.txt") needs to be cleared regularly, or it grows to massive proportions.  However, I do not want to stop pianobar to clear the file.

I have tried running `> pianobarout.txt` as well as `echo "" > pianobarout.txt`, but both cause the system's resources to spike heavily for almost 30 seconds, causing the audio from pianobar to skip.  I tried removing the file, but it appears that the file is not recreated after being deleted, and I just lose the pipe.

I'm working from python, so if any library there can help, those are available to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are currently redirecting with truncation, like `yourprogram > file.txt`, try redirecting with appending: `yourprogram >> file.txt`.

There is a big difference between the two when the output file is truncated.

With appending redirection, data is written to the current end of the file. If you truncate it to 0 bytes, the next write will happen at position 0.

With truncating redirection, data is written wherever the last write left off in the file. If you truncate it to 0 bytes, writes will continue at byte 1073741824 where it last left off.

This results in a sparse file if the filesystem supports it (ext2-4 and most Unix fs do), or a long wait while the file is written out if it doesn't (like fat32). A long wait could also be caused by anything following the file, such as `tail -f`, which has to potentially catch up by reading a GB of zeroes.

Alternatives include `yourprogram | split -b 1G - output-`, which will write 1GB each to `output-aa`, `output-ab`, etc, letting you delete old files at your leasure.

Comment: I'm testing replacing > with >> in my initial call.  So far, it appears to be taking care of the issue, but I'll need to run it for a while to build up the lag, if it is a matter of catching up to a massive number of blank bytes.  Tentatively, Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?